# Is there a better way to pull duplicate strings out of a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, hash

I currently am looping through a log file pulling certain characteristics out. I have to check for a unique string if it is duplicated and if the string is duplicated then ignore that log. Currently, my code takes an absurd amount of time to run (or I'm in an infinite loop) yippey. Is there a better way to pull duplicates out of a file and check them for uniqueness?

```perl
close($handle);

$test = "testFile.txt";

open( $handle, '<', $domainAnalysis ) or die "Cannot open file: $!";
open( $hand,   '>', $test )           or die "Cannot open file: $!";

my %uniq;

while ( $search = <$handle> ) {

    if ( $search =~ /Mail ID: ([^:]*)\n/g ) {
        $uniq{$search}++;
    }

    my @sortedHash = sort keys %uniq;

    foreach $i (@sortedHash) {

        if ( $i eq $search ) {
            print $hand $search;
            print $hand scalar <$handle> for 1 .. 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am kinda stuck.

Edit:

It currently is reading a log file and pulling needed information to a new file. The new file is printed in the format of this

```
Mail ID: b12342534  
Domain : someEmail@email.com  
Status Message = Sent  

Mail ID: a32432234  
Domain : someEmail@email.com  
Status Message = Deferred
```

Output: well the program never actually stops. It takes forever and my patience won't let it run all the way.

Comment: please provide sample input/output as well http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Without sample data, it's hard to answer. But I think it'll be because your inner loop is getting steadily larger, and each iteration, you're sorting it.

Comment: Some _actual sample_ data is necessary. 'something like' isn't enough for us to help. (It  doesn't have to be 'real' data, but it has to have EXACTLY the right formatting)

Comment: How big is your log file?

Comment: @Borodin really large millions of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that inner loop - as you iterate the log, presumably you'll accumulate a significant number of 'Mail ID' entries.

And each loop, you sort them all, and then iterate them all and compare them.

And - more importantly - your `$search` that you're inserting into each hash is EACH LINE which means it'll be getting huge.

Anyway - I'd suggest given your input data, first off you use `$/`:

```
local $/ = ''; #read in paragraph mode.  
my %seen; 
while ( <$input> ) { 
    my ( $id ) = m/Mail ID: ([^:]*)/;
    print unless $seen{$id}++; 
}
```

And this will print only the first time a particular mail ID is spotted.

(Of course, if you only want to print *duplicates* you can use 'if' instead of 'unless')

Comment: Although if I wanted to redirect this to a file how would I do that? For  some reason if I used: 
print$handle unless $seen{$id}++;
its not working

Comment: To use the exact `print unless...` idiom, you need to use `select` to choose the default output - e.g. `select $handle;` - outside the loop is fine. Otherwise, if you want to do it explicitly: `print {$handle} $_ unless $seen{$id}++;`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to iterate over all the keys of a hash; it breaks the whole point of a hash

Suppose you wanted element `$arr[3]` of arra `@arr`, would you write this?

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#arr ) {
    if ( $i == 3 ) {
        print "Found: $arr[$i]\n";
    }
}
```

and so you can just access any previously-existing element of `%uniq` with `$uniq{$search}`

Secondly, you can simply test whether the element of `%uniq` is currently zero when you increment it

Like this

```
my $test           = 'testFile.txt';
my $domainAnalysis = '...';

open my $handle, '<', $domainAnalysis or die qq{Cannot open "$domainAnalysis": $!};
open my $hand,   '>', $test           or die qq{Cannot open "$test": $!};

my %uniq;

while ( my $search = <$handle> ) {

    next unless $search =~ /^Mail ID:/;

    if ( $uniq{$search}++ ) {
        print $hand $search;
        print $hand scalar <$handle> for 1 .. 2;
    }
}
```

You also *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` and declare all of your variables with `my` as close as possible to where they are first used

And `$hand` and `$handle` are dreadful names for file handles!

Comment: I suspect that it's looking for unique mail IDs, rather than unique lines in the file. (I'm not entirely sure though). And likewise - I assume that it's reading two extra lines from the file, because it's doing something with a record, but ...

Comment: @Sobrique: I just copied the existing functionality. It's another question if that doesn't work!